# The operation couldn't be completed (project name.ApiClient.api error 0.) getting this in payment intent method in stripe ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stripe-payments, strip

I'm getting "the operation couldn't be completed (project name.ApiClient.api error 0.)" in Stripe payment intent method call.

When i click on card number. I'm getting this message "The operation couldn't be completed (project name.ApiClient.api error 0.)".

I 'm not able to find solution.

Comment: Please provide more details, including the code you're using, the stack trace for the error, screenshots, etc.  The more detail you can provide the better.